# Jtable Delete not Deleting

Tags: javascript, php, html, jtable

I'm having a problem with the Jquery Jtable plugin delete method. The variable 'email' is passed between pages and into the .php file. The list action function works, so I know it isn't a connection issue. My database name is maps.
 Below is my code:
Javascript:

```
var emailHolder="email@email.com";
var file="c";
function loadForm()
{
$("#my-form" ).dialog( "open" );
}   

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Prepare jTable
        $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'Table of people',
            actions: {
                listAction: 'PersonActions.php?action=list&emailHolder='+emailHolder,
                deleteAction: 'PersonActions.php?action=delete&emailHolder='+emailHolder+"&fileHolder="+file
            },
    fields: {
                filename: {
                key:true,
                    title: 'File',
                    width: '40%'

                },
                email: {
                title:'User',
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list:false

                }
            }
        });
Php:



 {
    $email= $_GET['emailHolder'];
        //Delete from database
        $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM maps WHERE (email='$email' and filename = " . $_POST["filename"] . ");");

        //Return result to jTable
        $jTableResult = array();
        $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
        print json_encode($jTableResult);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure try removing 'key' from 'email' field in your jtable